# Vertices of Connected Planar

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

(a) A connected planar graph $G$ has $20$ faces, and every vertex of $G$ has degree exactly $4$.

Find the number of vertices of $G$.

(b) A connected planar graph has $26$ faces and $V$ vertices, and all its vertices have the same degree. What are all possible values of $V$?

I tried drawing the diagram for part a, but it got too big and I'm not sure how to do part b. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: hint : what is a key formula related to **planar** graphs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to draw anything for $a$. If there are $v$ vertices, all of degree $4$, there are $2v$ edges. By Euler's relation, $v+20-2v=2$, which solves to $v=18$.

Similarly, for (b) let there be $v$ vertices of degree $d$; there are $vd/2$ edges and $v+26-vd/2=2$ or $24=v(d/2-1)$. Obviously we must also have $d\le v-1$, and so we have
$$(v,d)\in\{(12,6),(16,5),(24,4),(48,3)\}$$
The $(12,6)$ case is also eliminated by a theorem saying that a planar graph can have at most $2v-4$ faces. So the graph may have $16,24,48$ vertices.

Comment: You only took $d$ to be even, but it could be odd as long as $v$ is even. you also have the pairs $(16,5)$ and $(48,3)$

Comment: @ThomasLesgourgues Please delete your comment.